# How to open previous camera of camera surfaceview when press back button in android

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I am developing one camera application. In that am displaying camera surfaceview. In that am capturing camera surfaceview using front and back cameras. when captured image will be displayed in next activity. all is working fine. In that default camera is back camera when switch is clicked front will be displayed again am click switch it will move front to back it is process. But when am click switch button front camera displayed capture image and it is displayed in next activity. when am press back button it will open back camera. which camera is opened in switching that will be still there after press back button. How can i do this. anyone please help me.

```
Surfaceview.class


*public class CameraSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{    
private static final int ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN = 0;
public static Camera camera = null;
public static SurfaceHolder holder = null;
private CameraCallback callback = null;
private boolean isStarted = true;
public static int camId ;
public static int noofcameras;
public static  CameraInfo info;
Activity mActivity;
public static SharedPreferences pref;
Camera.Parameters params;
int currentZoomLevel ;
int maxZoomLevel ;
int a;
Editor ed;
Context context;
boolean gg;
int num;



public CameraSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        initialize(context);
}
public CameraSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);

        initialize(context);

}
public CameraSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        initialize(context);
}

public void setCallback(CameraCallback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
}

public void startPreview(){
        camera.startPreview();
}

public void startTakePicture(){
        if(camera != null)
        {
            Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            /*if(pref.getBoolean("flashlight",true))
            {
                parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
            }else
            {
                parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            }

            if(pref.getBoolean("flashsound",true))
            {

            }else
            {

            }*/

            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            //camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                        takePicture();
                }
        });
        }

      }

     public void takePicture() {
        camera.takePicture(
                        new ShutterCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onShutter(){
                                        if(null != callback) callback.onShutter();
                                }
                        },
                        new PictureCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
                                        if(null != callback) callback.onRawPictureTaken(data, camera);
                                }
                        },
                        new PictureCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
                                        if(null != callback) callback.onJpegPictureTaken(data, camera);
                                }
                        });
                }

           @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
     if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(camId, info);
     orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
     int rotation = 0;
     if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
     } /*else {  // back-facing camera
         rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
     }*/
     params.setRotation(rotation);
     }



    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
        if(null != camera && isStarted)
        {

            /*int angleToRotate=CommonMethods.getRoatationAngle(mActivity, Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(angleToRotate);*/
            //params=camera.getParameters();
            //onOrientationChanged(180);
            //setCameraDisplayOrientation(mActivity, camId, camera);
                camera.startPreview();
               // camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);



        }/*else{
             camera.startPreview();
        }*/
        }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


    //a=1;
    camId=findCameraID();
    noofcameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    info = new CameraInfo(); 
    Camera.getCameraInfo(camId, info);


    camera=Camera.open(camId);


    // safeCameraOpen(camId);


        try {

            //camera=Camera.open(camId);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            params = camera.getParameters();

                params.set("orientation", "portrait");
                params.setRotation(90);
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                camera.setParameters(params);


        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
       // isStarted = false;

        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
         }

          @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private void initialize(Context context) {
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.tattoocameraa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        holder = getHolder();

        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
       // gg=pref.getBoolean("back", true);
        //gg=pref.getBoolean("back", false);


        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public  int findCameraID() {
    int foundId = -1;
    int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    System.out.println("no of cameras are "+numCams);
    for (int camId = 0; camId < numCams; camId++) {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo(); 
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camId, info); 
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            foundId = camId;
            break;
        }else 
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            foundId = camId;
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundId;
    }

   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
    boolean qOpened = false;

       try {
             camera = Camera.open(id);
            qOpened = (camera != null);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       /*if(camera != null)
       {
                                            ((MainActivity)MainActivity.activity).setSeekbarInitialize(camera.getParameters().getMaxZoom(), camera.getParameters().getZoom());
       }*/
    return qOpened;    
      }

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "ShowToast" })
public void openFrontFacingCamera() {
    //numberOfCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){


        camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;

        try {

            ed=pref.edit();

            if(camera!=null)
            {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();
            camera=null;
            }

            camera = Camera.open(camId);
            a=2;
            //ed.putBoolean("front", true);
            ed.putInt("front", 5);
            //setCamera(mCamera);

            //onOrientationChanged(0);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                            if(null != callback) callback.onPreviewFrame(data, camera);
                    }
            });

            camera.startPreview();
            //previewing = true;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        }catch (IOException e) {}
           }

     else if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){

        camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        try {

            ed=pref.edit();

            if(camera!=null)
            {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();
            camera=null;
            }

            camera=Camera.open(camId);
            a=1;
            //ed.putBoolean("front", false);
            ed.putInt("front", 6);
             //setCamera(mCamera);

            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                            if(null != callback) callback.onPreviewFrame(data, camera);
                    }
            });

            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        }catch (IOException e) {}
          }
       }


        /*@SuppressLint("NewApi")
      public void openBackCam() {
        //if (gg==false) {


    a=1;

    ed=pref.edit();
    ed.putBoolean("back", false);
    try

    {
        if(camera != null)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();               
            camera = null;
        }
        camera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        if(null != callback) callback.onPreviewFrame(data, camera);
                }
        });
        camera.startPreview();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
    }
     //}

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
     public void openFrontCam() {

    a=2;

    ed=pref.edit();
    ed.putBoolean("back", true);
    try
    {
        if(camera != null)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();               
            camera = null;
        }

        camera = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        //onOrientationChanged(90);
        camera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        if(null != callback) callback.onPreviewFrame(data, camera);
                }
        });
        camera.startPreview();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

      } 
      */
     public void zoom()
      {

        params=camera.getParameters();
        maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
        if (currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel) {
            currentZoomLevel++;
            params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
            camera.setParameters(params);
           }
        /*if(currentZoomLevel < 50){
        params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel= currentZoomLevel + 10);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);   
        }else{

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no zoom here..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/

      }
     public void unzoom()
     {
        params=camera.getParameters();
        maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
        if (currentZoomLevel > 0) {
        currentZoomLevel--;
        params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        }
        /*if(currentZoomLevel >0){
        params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel= currentZoomLevel - 10);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }else{
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }
       */
       }


    public void setZoom(int progress) {
     try
     {
        Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setZoom(progress);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
     }catch(Exception e)
     {

     }

     }
     }*





cameraclass.class


public class CameraSwitch extends Activity implements CameraCallback  {
private CameraSurface camerasurface = null;
private FrameLayout pannel;
public static Activity activity;
private  File f;
public static File mediaFile;
private int screenWidth,screenHeight;
public static final int DETECT_NONE = 0;
public static final int DETECT_WHISTLE = 1;
public static int selectedDetection = DETECT_NONE;
public static boolean isCapturing = false;
private Button camChange,capture,flashlight;
public static  boolean isFrontCamera = false;
private SharedPreferences pref;
private int count;
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
ImageView imm,aboveimg;
private int[] tattoos;
Button tattooselect,zoomin,zoomout;
GridView gview;
Bitmap backimage;
public RelativeLayout layout;
Bitmap bitmapPicture;
public static File outFile;
public static String fileName;
Camera mcamera;
public static int camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
Camera.Parameters paramss;
public Editor ee;
boolean bb;
boolean cc;
int ss;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tattoos = new int[]{
                R.drawable.tattoo1, R.drawable.tattoo2,R.drawable.tattoo3,R.drawable.tattoo4,R.drawable.tattoo5,R.drawable.tattoo6,
                R.drawable.tattoo7, R.drawable.tattoo8,R.drawable.tattoo9,R.drawable.tattoo10,R.drawable.tattoo11,R.drawable.tattoo12,
                R.drawable.tattoo13,R.drawable.tattoo14,R.drawable.tattoo15, R.drawable.tattoo16,R.drawable.tattoo17,R.drawable.tattoo18,
                R.drawable.tattoo19,R.drawable.tattoo20, R.drawable.tattoo21,R.drawable.tattoo22,R.drawable.tattoo23,R.drawable.tattoo24, 
                R.drawable.tattoo25,R.drawable.tattoo26,R.drawable.tattoo27,R.drawable.tattoo28,R.drawable.tattoo29,R.drawable.tattoo30,
                R.drawable.tattoo31,R.drawable.tattoo32,R.drawable.tattoo33,R.drawable.tattoo34,R.drawable.tattoo35

        };

        pref = getSharedPreferences("com.example.tattoocameraa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ee=pref.edit();
        /*ee=pref.edit();
        ee.putBoolean("vv", false);*/

        CameraSwitch.activity = this;

        pannel = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.pannel);
        layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
        imm=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        aboveimg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        aboveimg.setOnTouchListener(new Touchhimage());

        camChange = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        capture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        //flashlight = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flashlight);
        //galleryImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.galleryimg);
        tattooselect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        gview=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        zoomin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        zoomout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


        zoomin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camerasurface.zoom();
            }
        });

        zoomout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camerasurface.unzoom();
            }
        });

        tattooselect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                gview.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(getApplicationContext())); 
                gview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        gview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "visible", 1000).show();
                backimage= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), tattoos[position]);
                scaling(backimage);
                aboveimg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                aboveimg.setImageBitmap(Utils.camerabitmap);
                gview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        /*if(pref.getBoolean("flashlight",true))
        {
            flashlight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flash);
        }else
        {
            flashlight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flash2);
        }*/



        /*if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH))
        {
            flashlight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else
        {
            flashlight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        flashlight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try
                {
                    Editor edit = pref.edit();
                    if(pref.getBoolean("flashlight",true))
                    {
                        edit.putBoolean("flashlight",false);
                        flashlight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flash2);
                    }else
                    {
                        edit.putBoolean("flashlight",true);
                        flashlight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flash);
                    }
                    edit.commit();
                }catch(Exception e)
                {

                }

            }
        });*/


        if(Camera.getNumberOfCameras()>1)
        {
            camChange.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else
        {
            camChange.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }




     camChange.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                camerasurface.openFrontFacingCamera();
                /*if(isFrontCamera)
                {
                    //ee.putBoolean("back", true);
                    camerasurface.openBackCam();
                    isFrontCamera=false;

                }else
                {   
                    //ee=pref.edit();
                    //ee.putBoolean("back", false);
                    camerasurface.openFrontCam();
                    isFrontCamera = true;


                }*/

            }
        });


    capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*  if(isCapturing==false)
            {
                isCapturing=true;
                camerasurface.startTakePicture();
                //setupPictureMode();

            }*/
            camerasurface.startTakePicture();   


        }
    });

    setupPictureMode();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

}

```
private void setupPictureMode(){
    camerasurface = new CameraSurface(this);

    pannel.addView(camerasurface, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    camerasurface.setCallback(this);

}

private void resetCam() {

    imm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
    camerasurface.startTakePicture();
    //isCapturing=true;
    //preview.setCamera(camera);
}
public void scaling(Bitmap backimage)
{


    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    //   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
    ///  in.close();
    //  in = null;

    // save width and height
    //  inWidth = options.outWidth;
    //  inHeight = options.outHeight;

    // decode full image pre-resized
    //  in = new FileInputStream(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    // calc rought re-size (this is no exact resize)
    //options.inSampleSize = Math.max(inWidth/screenWidth, inHeight/screenHeight);
    // decode full image
    // Bitmap roughBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);

    // calc exact destination size
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    RectF inRect = new RectF(0, 0, backimage.getWidth(), backimage.getHeight());
    RectF outRect = new RectF(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    m.setRectToRect(inRect, outRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    float[] values = new float[9];
    m.getValues(values);

    // resize bitmap
    Utils.camerabitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(backimage, imm.getWidth(), imm.getHeight(), true);

}

private void refreshGallery(File file) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onShutter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRawPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "ShowToast" })
@Override
public void onJpegPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
                new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(camId, info);
    try
    {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null ){
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);

            if (bitmap != null){
                   int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                   int h = bitmap.getHeight();
                   // Setting post rotate to 90
                   Matrix mtx = new Matrix();

                   mtx.postRotate(0);
                  if(camerasurface.a==1)
                   {
                       mtx.postRotate(0);
                   }
                   else if (camerasurface.a==2) {
                    mtx.postRotate(270);
                }

              Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);

            //imm.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    imm.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);

            }

            imm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            File file;

            layout.getRootView();
            layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap m=layout.getDrawingCache();

            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
            {  
                file =new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"WhistleCamera");
                if(!file.exists())
                {
                    file.mkdirs();

                } 

                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(count));

                f = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+file.separator+ "IMG_"+timeStamp+".png");
            }

            FileOutputStream ostream;

            try {
                ostream = new FileOutputStream(f);
                m.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, ostream);
                //m.recycle();

                try {
                    ostream.close();
                    refreshGallery(f);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


            Intent i=new Intent(CameraSwitch.this,Imageshare.class);
            i.putExtra("imagepath", f.getAbsolutePath());
            startActivity(i);
            resetCam();
            //camerasurface.startPreview(); 
            //mediaFile.delete();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {

    }finally{
        isCapturing = false;
    }

}

private Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.postRotate(i);

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);

}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(){

    /*File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyCameraApp");

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }*/

    // Create a media file name
    //String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    mediaFile = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/WhistleCamera");
    if(!mediaFile.exists())
    {
        mediaFile.mkdirs();
    }

    mediaFile = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/WhistleCamera",
            "filename.jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}
@Override
public String onGetVideoFilename() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the question properly.

Restart your camera preview in `onResume()`

Save your current camera being used in `onPause()`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can u please tell me in coding